# Why does declaring a struct inside another header file cause a LNK2001 error?

Tags: c++, struct, static

I'm trying to make a text-based console video game in c++.

I have an Inventory class with a header and a source file. In the same header file I have declared a struct called `STRINGSIZES` with two integer members called name and description. They are used to store the length that should be used when displaying the Items, or from which length the name will be shortened. The header file "Inventory.h" looks something like this:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

struct STRINGSIZES {    //the fixed Size with which Inventory lists will be printed
    int name;
    int description;
};

class Inventory
{
public:
    //some unrelated code
    Inventory();

    static void setStringSizes(int name, int description);
private:
    static STRINGSIZES stringSizes;
};
```

In the Inventory.cpp file, I define the `setStringSizes()` method like so:

```
void Inventory::setStringSizes(int name, int description)
{
    stringSizes.name = name;
    stringSizes.description = description;
}
```

In my main Source.cpp file, I am firstly calling this method.

Now when I try to compile this I get the errors:

1>Inventory.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int stringSizeNames::name" (?name@stringSizeNames@@2HA)

1>Inventory.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int stringSizeNames::description" (?description@stringSizeNames@@2HA)

What is the problem here?

Comment: Is `STRINGSIZES` a macro for `stringSizeNames`? That is really confusing.

Comment: @walnut no, it's just the name of the struct.

Comment: Then your error message is not about the code you are showing. The error message references `stringSizeNames` which is doesn't appear anywhere in your shown code.

Comment: @walnut oh, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message refers to a variable which declaration you did not show in the question. But I think it is the same problem as with the static data member `stringSizes`.

Within the class definition this data member

```
static STRINGSIZES stringSizes;
```

is a declaration that is not a definition.

You have to define it outside the class definition in the cpp file for example like

```
STRINGSIZES Inventory::stringSizes;
```

If your compiler supports the C++17 Standard then you could define the data member inside the class definition the following way

```
class Inventory
{
    //...
    inline static STRINGSIZES stringSizes = {};
};
```

Comment: The first approach worked, thanks. The one with the `inline` keyword didn't, though I have no idea why as I'm using the newest Windows 10 SDK

Comment: @joriba If you are saying about MS Visual C++ then maybe you should set the project properties specifying the version of used C++.